# CS:GO Trade Up Contract Signing?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

You can actually "sign" a trade up contract in CS:GO with your mouse (draw stuff). Does this have any impact on anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, no.  Nothing happens.  The weapon you get from the completed contract would have the same odds as a contract that you didn't sign. That's an interesting tidbit you mentioned however.

Comment: Scribbling random gibberish, signing nicely, or doing nothing hasn't changed anything for me. All end in the same outcome.

Answer (score -2):

It does, actually, but not noticable. It takes the positions of the pixels of your random drawings and includes them in the random generator.

Comment: Is there any source for this?